# Set colorbar range for an mlab surface

Tags: python, plot, colorbar, mayavi

I've looked around on the internet but I haven't found a solution.

I'm plotting different surfaces in the same figure with `mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh)`. I'd like to plot them with the same colorbar.

In this figure the right part of the surfaces is at the same temerature, but since the colorbar range is different for each surface the color is different.
I think there should be something like `matplotlib.tricontourf(...,levels=...)` to fix the colorbar range.

[image: surfacemesh]

How can I set the colorbar range using `mlab`?

Comment: Could you post a short example of what you are trying to achieve? It would be much easier for potential answers to be made. Stackoverflow has a [help page about it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the built-in documentation of mlab. From `help(mlab.pipeline.surface)`:

```
:vmax: vmax is used to scale the colormap.
       If None, the max of the data will be used

:vmin: vmin is used to scale the colormap.
       If None, the min of the data will be used
```

In other words, you need to compute the global minimum and global maximum of your data across every dataset, and set the same extrema for every surface of yours. Note that you can do the exact same (with the exact same keywords even) with matplotlib's 3d plotting methods.

Tangential note: your use case might also benefit from some transparency, since your surfaces are likely to overlap one another which might hinder the visualization. The two keywords that come to mind are `opacity` and perhaps (albeit less likely) `transparent`:

```
:opacity: The overall opacity of the vtk object. Must be a float.
          Default: 1.0
:transparent: make the opacity of the actor depend on the
              scalar.
```